# Logo Design / Picture Validation

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

Php / ASP.Net / Jquery

I am working on a small blogging website, where i am looking forward to keep a logo.

for Instance : abc"Chillie Image" def.

When you right click on StackOverflow - It doesnt show the option for saving the image. It shows the option to save as target in .html?
I expecting .. similarly

How to store the logo inside HTML Tags rather than storing in image tag

Comment: There is an arrow up-oriented on the left :D I'm happy I've helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it as a background in a `<div>`, for example.

```
<div style="background-color: yellow; 
            background-image:url('moon.jpg'); 
            width:400px; height: 400px; 
            background-repeat:no-repeat"> Hello World! </div>
```

This actually works. You can have the logo as a background.

Comment: if you keep it in div tag  <div> <table> <tr> <td> <img>  <td/><tr/><table/> <div/>   - It will not work. Div is just a Placeholder. StackOverflow is mentioned as Font - Title Designer - But, how they stored the logo image

Comment: How to select your answer and vote it? It works, Thanks for sharing the concept.